# display EditText Above the listview

Tags: android, xml

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnEmoji"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_msg_panel_smiles"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edtMessage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />





    <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
        android:id="@+id/emojicon_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnChatSend"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnEmoji"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:maxLines="5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChatSend"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_chat_send"
        />


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_SwipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edtMessage">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstvuChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edtMessage"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"

        android:divider="@null" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/emojicon_edit_text"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/emojicon_edit_text"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnChatSend"
        android:onClick="chooseImage"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EmojiconEditText is displaying below the ListView.
typed text not visible properly.
i want to display edittext above the listView.
i am using compile project(':supernova-emoji-library') for Emojis

thanks**

Comment: Replace `android:layout_above="@+id/edtMessage"` with `android:layout_below="@+id/emojicon_edit_text"` in your listview ..

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
android:layout_above="edtMessage"
```

In the listview but there is no edtMessage

Comment: Use Linearlayout instead of Relativeview or write android:layout_above="lstvuChat" in the supernova_emoji_library